# Smarty PHP Multi-Select

Tags: php, smarty

I am using a piece of software which I believe is using Smarty PHP. I would like to turn one of the drop-down menus from a select to a multi-select. Here is the current code

```
{html_options options=$brands selected=$val['brands']}
```

What would be the equivalent in a multi-select?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you need to add `multiple` attribute to a `select`-tag:

```
<select name="" multiple>
    {html_options options=$brands selected=$val['brands']}
</select>
```

Comment: If answer solves your problem - you can __accept__ it.